# Impossible to push large folder to remote Git and Github

Tags: php, git, github

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtzR2.png)i wanna push a folder to remote but the probleme that i can't use git lfs for all files 
anyone have a solution for that please and thanks.

error:

> remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git
>   Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.

Comment: What kind of files there and why you are so eagerly need them under Git?

Comment: And why can't you use git lfs?

Comment: @0andriy it's a ZIP

Comment: @kerbholz i try it but is not work !

Comment: File template/Hotel Spice/hts-cache/new.zip is 100.59 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

Comment: `/hts-cache/...` ... do you really need a cache file pushed to git?

Comment: @kerbholz no i dont need cache but i can't clear cache in my folder !

Comment: Might want to read about `gitignore` and how you can ignore files/folders to be handled in git. Good luck

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history

Comment: @kerbholz i did and is not worked for me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because GitHub's limit for any push is 100MB maximum, see the documentation here:

[Conditions for large files](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/conditions-for-large-files)

As the error message on your console says, you can try Git Large File Storage(Git LFS)

[Versioning large files](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/versioning-large-files)

[Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com)

Comment: i try it with GIT LFS but is not working for my file zip !!!

Comment: @Garrix what if you unzip it?

Comment: i did it but when i do the push the same message error ! 
"
/hts-cache/new.zip is 100.59 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB